# Does selenium have a way to access a value that is generated after a specific action?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, nunit

Lets say I press a button, and need to obtain the URL that gets generated with specific query parameters after that said button is pressed.

```
    public string pressAButton()
        {
            button.Click();
            var URL = driver.Url.ToString();
            return URL;
        }
```

I essentially need to create a URL with that button press
and navigate to it to do some other stuff on specific days of the week.

Once I have this url I need another method to navigate to it but this new method **has** to be used for a separate test, and it would need the URL generated from the first method.

Would selenium have a way to handle this? The new test cannot call the pressAButton method in it, is there a way to obtain the value from the first method in a separate test?

Comment: Can you at least post some pseudo code for how you want to use the URL? Is this other test in the same test class? Can you post the code for one of the tests?

Comment: So for the second test the main thing I need to do is below, the rest of the test is just simple button clicks, test 2 is going to be programmed to execute a few days after test 1
```driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(valueFromFirstMethodInTest1);
```
And yes they are both in the same test class

In order to mimic proper end to end testing the tests need to fire a few days apart from one another because of the application.

Comment: Ok. The important part is the tests will be executed some number of **days** apart - as in *not during the same test run*. That makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to access a value from one test in another test, and the two tests are run in different test runs, you will need to save the URL to a text file. When the second test runs, open that text file, read the URL and use it.

**Test #1**

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

button.Click();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(button));

File.WriteAllText(@"path\to\url.txt", driver.Url);
```

Note: `driver.Url` is already a string. No need to call `driver.Url.ToString()`.

**Test #2 (run some number of days later)**

```
var urlFromPreviousTest = File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\url.txt");

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlFromPreviousTest);
```

Since you have two separate invocations of tests, you need some sort of persistent storage. Saving the URL to a file or database is your only option here. No in-memory solutions will work, because the existing memory allocated for a test is discarded once the test runner closes down.